# R read_html running indefinitely

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this website: [edmunds cost to own data](https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/rx-350/2019/cost-to-own/?style=401771404). But whenever I try to run `read_html("link")` nothing happens as far as I can tell it just runs indefinitely;

```
library(rvest)
    
htm <- read_html("https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/rx-350/2019/cost-to-own/?style=401771404")
```

I have also tried things like:   But they all just run forever. **Why can't I read this html?**

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)


h <- handle("https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/rx-350/2019/cost-to-own/?style=401771404")
res <- GET(handle = h)
  
#parse the HTML
resXML <- htmlParse(content(res, as = "text"))
```

Comment: What content from the page you want? the table?

Comment: this is a curl specific problem. I tried in a console (windows) it hangs altogether.

Comment: Originally I ran this on a PC and I tried running it on a mac and ran but it threw the error `error in open.connection(x,"rb) : HTTP error 403` even when I tried running different links from the same website. *yes it is the table I am trying to pull* @JilberUrbina